# Aws Glue throws error on running python script with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, aws-glue

I have a python code that scrapes data from websites using Beautifulsoup and it works fine in Jupyter. I am trying to run the same script in aws glue and added the following job parameter in the glue job key: `--additional-python-modules value:bs4`.The job is failing with the error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`

```
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import boto3

from io import StringIO
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by including pip install in the script? See this link for working with additional modules - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Comment: Added  the following job parameter in the glue job    key:--additional-python-modules   value:beautifulsoup4 .The job is failing with the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'

Comment: There's a list of modules available already with Glue on that page, beautifulsoup4 is not in that list. You would need to zip the module yourself, put it on S3 and use the path, there are instructions on the same page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I read through the instructions in the aws docs but as someone new to both Python and AWS ,its a bit difficult to navigate through the steps. Thanks for responding to the query @RohitP

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using the following

```
%additional_python_modules beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
```

It appears that you have to spell the entire package.